# How to incorporate Weka Naive Bayes model into Java Code

Tags: classification, bayesian

I run a training set using Naive Bayes classifier using Weka. The resulted model is shown below. My question is:

a. Is it possible to incorporate the model into my java code?

b. If so, how can I do that?

c. If not, what should I do?

Thanks.

=== Classifier model (full training set) ===

Naive Bayes (simple)

Class A: P(C) = 0.42074928

Attribute mcv
'All'
1

Attribute alkphos
'All'
1

Attribute sgpt
'All'
1

Attribute sgot
'All'
1

Attribute gammagt
'(-inf-20.5]'   '(20.5-inf)'
0.54421769  0.45578231

Attribute drinks
'All'
1

Class B: P(C) = 0.57925072

Attribute mcv
'All'
1

Attribute alkphos
'All'
1

Attribute sgpt
'All'
1

Attribute sgot
'All'
1

Attribute gammagt
'(-inf-20.5]'   '(20.5-inf)'
0.30693069  0.69306931

Attribute drinks
'All'
1

Time taken to build model: 0 seconds

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to build your naive Bayes model in Java using Weka.  Once built you can use this model to predict the outcome of test instances using Weka.

A good source to begin using Weka in your Java code is [here](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+WEKA+in+your+Java+code), and a more advanced tool is the Weka API [here](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/).

Provided you are able to load your training instances (called "train" below) and testing instances (called "test" below), the naive Bayes model can be built and then used as follows:

```
    //build model
    NaiveBayes model=new NaiveBayes();
    model.buildClassifier(train);

    //use
    Evaluation eval_train = new Evaluation(test);
    eval_train.evaluateModel(model,test);
```